similarity score in between 2D arrays of different size

These are 2D (z=0) poly lines in 3D application Blender and they are used as paths. I would like to know the similarity score between them.
It’s important to distinguish between the concepts of similarity and distance. Similarity measures how similar or close two series are to each other, while distance quantifies the dissimilarity between two series. The smaller the distance, the more similar the two patterns are considered, as they require fewer adjustments for optimal alignment.
In my case:

Paths may have different lengths or number of points.
Paths may be similar but slightly scaled on either axis.
Points distribution may be different or not aligned.
Starting points will surely be aligned but ending points may or may not.

Initially, I did some tests using distance based function using scipy but because of scaling issue, they produce a higher score which is correct as per the scaled data but I can't make use of it.
import numpy as np
# path data from blender
PATH1 = np.array([
    [ 0.        , -0.54760742],
    [ 0.06086956, -0.01623535],
    [ 0.08695652,  0.33010864],
    [ 0.12173913,  0.55926514],
    [ 0.14782609,  0.47113037],
    [ 0.2       , -0.17211914],
    [ 0.2173913 , -0.26098633],
    [ 0.2521739 , -0.18804932],
    [ 0.31304348,  0.33068848],
    [ 0.33913043,  0.46157837],
    [ 0.36521739,  0.36813354],
    [ 0.39130434,  0.12088013],
    [ 0.42608696, -0.06130981],
    [ 0.5043478 ,  0.02139282],
    [ 0.56521738,  0.22866821],
    [ 0.60000002,  0.16775513],
    [ 0.65217394, -0.1048584 ],
    [ 0.77391303, -0.36459351],
    [ 0.81739128, -0.26113892],
    [ 0.87826085,  0.21520996],
    [ 0.9217391 ,  0.19732666],
    [ 1.        , -0.51672363]])

PATH2 = np.array([
    [ 0.        , -0.57351685],
    [ 0.08849557,  0.20959473],
    [ 0.13274336,  0.45080566],
    [ 0.15929204,  0.35235596],
    [ 0.20353982, -0.20309448],
    [ 0.2300885 , -0.27749634],
    [ 0.2920354 ,  0.08712769],
    [ 0.3539823 ,  0.27789307],
    [ 0.38053098,  0.24447632],
    [ 0.43362832, -0.03421021],
    [ 0.51327431,  0.09094238],
    [ 0.60176992,  0.09771729],
    [ 0.66371679, -0.11819458],
    [ 0.71681416, -0.17974854],
    [ 0.79646015, -0.39971924],
    [ 0.84070796, -0.18743896],
    [ 0.88495576,  0.23342896],
    [ 0.90265489,  0.25582886],
    [ 0.92920351,  0.20352173],
    [ 0.94690263,  0.08068848],
    [ 1.        , -0.50335693]])

I also did some tests using fastdtw, correlate2d, and cosine similarity but not able to figure out the correct one for the requirement and their results look unpredictable to me.

If the paths are of different length, would an accurate comparison truncate the longer path, or interpolate the shorter path up to the same length as the longer path?

If the paths are scaled in either axis, should that count against the comparison score, or should correction occur before calculating the score?

For the scaling problem, I will normalize the path in between (0-1) on both axes. For different lengths, I'm not sure right now but if keeping the length the same improves the accuracy of the score, then I'll go for it.
